# Dynamically Parsing a URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Give the following URL:

http://www.example.com/file_to_load/slug1/slug2/slug_n

I would like my .htaccess to load **file_to_load.php** (or whichever filename takes at position in the URL)

In addition, file_to_load.php is located one directory down from .htaccess

```
.htaccess
    |_subdirectory
        |_file_to_load.php
```

My current .htaccess is as follows (redirecting all requests to index.php):

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

How can I rewrite my .htaccess to perform the above?

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: an `.htaccess` in subdirectory would override the main `.htaccess` so you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can to like this in subdirectory :

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file_to_load.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: this loads file_to_load.php but I need it to load a file of arbitrary name dynamically

Comment: I don't think it's possible like this... You can try to do the stuff with PHP, parsing URL, get file content and send that

Comment: I have done exactly that but was told doing it that way presents a security exploit. was told some basic routing in htaccess is the most robust solution

Comment: Can you share what you have done in php, it will be easier to rewrite that in .htacces (since it is a little unclear what exactly are you asking)